# Is there a simple test that can differentiate menstrual blood " period blood" from spotting blood?

Tags: human-biology, gynecology

I have a simple question: If I give two samples of blood; one from a the menstrual period and one from spotting, is there a simple way to know which one is from the period and which one is from spotting " normal, non uterus " blood? 
Thanks

Comment: Spotting is "normal, non uterus"? Where does spotting come from if not the uterus?

Comment: agree with above comment - menstrual blood and blood from "spotting" are likely both uterine (except in the case of trauma, vaginal laceration, etc)

Comment: @VanceLAlbaugh - in which case(s), it would not be "normal".

Comment: @anongoodnurse exactly

Comment: The blood during the period is from the enlarged lining of the uterus caused by estrogen. spotting may be from the uterus but not related to period

Comment: My instinct is that it depends on where it's coming from. Menstrual product, either from menstruation or an endometrial condition would probably show evidence of decidualized glands. Blood from something like a leiomyoma or a tubal rupture (from, say ectopic pregnancy) would probably not show as many glands and would look more like a regular peripheral smear. That's my guess, but I don't have sources, so comment and not an answer.